# Parsing this JSON to obtain a human readable list

Tags: json, parsing

I have a JSON file whit this structure. For every URL field, we have a RESULT field which contains hundreds of LINKS. Would it be somehow possible to parse it and obtain a (ie. csv) list which contains all the LINKS for every URL?

```
 [{
    "url": "https://example.org/yyy",
    "result": "{\"links\":[{\"link\":\"https://example.org/xxx/xxx\",\"text\":\"\"
},
{
    \"link\":\"https://example.org/xxx/xxx\",\"text\":\"\"
},
{
    \"link\":\"https://example.org/xxx/xxx\",\"text\":\"yyy\"}[.......]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure. You can parse the JSON with `JSON.parse`, iterate over the array and process the information in any way you like. Do you have a specific question about any of these steps? Does [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) help you?

Comment: @FelixKling, he did not mention "javascript", so `JSON.parse` might be for another case

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Ugh, you are right... jumped to conclusions too quickly.

Comment: @FelixKling, that's because you like javascript very much ))

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Is it that obvious, yes? ;) :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). If `data.json` contains the sample data

```
[{"url": "https://example.org/yyy", "result": "{\"links\":[{\"link\":\"https://example.org/xx1/xx1\",\"text\":\"\"},{\"link\":\"https://example.org/xx2/xx2\",\"text\":\"\"}]}"}]
```

then the command

```
$ jq -Mr '.[].result | fromjson | .links[].link' data.json
```

produces

```
https://example.org/xx1/xx1
https://example.org/xx2/xx2
```

If you would like both the url and the links, the command

```
$ jq -Mr '.[] | .url as $url | .result | fromjson | "\($url),\(.links[].link)"' data.json
```

produces

```
https://example.org/yyy,https://example.org/xx1/xx1
https://example.org/yyy,https://example.org/xx2/xx2
```